# make a div grow and shrink based on the browser window size

Tags: html, css

I am making a very simple html page and would like to know how to do the following two things for my page:

1. I have a container div and would like to put the container div in the center of the page.
2. The container div will grow and shrink when I resize the windows size.

I wrote the attached code but the container is always sticked on the left and it won't change the size when I resize the window.

```
<title>Demo</title>
<head>This is a demo</head>
<style>
#nav
{
background-color: red;
float: left;
width: 200px;
position:relative;

}

#detail
{
background-color: green;
float : right;
width: 800px;
position:relative;
}

div.testDetail 
{
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#container
{
width:1000px;
position:relative;
}
</style>

<hr>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="nav">
    <ul>Tests</ul>
</div>
<div id="detail">
    <div class="testDetail">
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test3.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <image style="float:right;margin:5px;" src="test4.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"/>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
</div>
<body>
```

Did I miss something here? Any help will be appreciate!

Thanks.

Comment: use % size, rather than PX size, I.E `width:80%;`

Comment: Or, better, don't float it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<div id="my-div">
  ...content goes here
</div>
```

CSS

```
#my-div{
  //For center align
  margin: 0 auto;
  // For grow & shrink as per screen size change values as per your requirements
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: can i do it for `<header>`?

Answer (score 3):

A shorthand method of Matt's CSS to do the horizontal centering is

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

The 0 will dictate the top and bottom margin's and the auto the left and right margins. If you want a margin on the top/bottom you can change the 0 to anything you want(ie `margin: 20px auto;` .

Answer (score 2):

The best way to center an object, especially a `<div>`, is to use the following CSS:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Without a fixed margin, the object will be centered.

For the resizing, make sizes relative (e.g. 40%) to the page rather than absolute (e.g. 400px).